# Your experience launching an application on BlackBerry AppWorld?

Tags: blackberry, mobile, blackberry-world

I'm looking for some experiences launching a mobile application on BlackBerry AppWorld. I'll be in a position to launch one shortly and I want to make sure I can avoid any potential pitfalls.

Did you have any issues? If so were these easily fixed by yourself or RIM? What sort of other advice can you offer?

Comment: We've had significant issues thus far, and are still unable to resolve everything as yet.  We simply get useless "Error installing" messages after download.

Comment: Exactly one of the reasons I've made this post. I think especially with a new thing like AppWorld, it'll be beneficial to those trying to get apps to market to have a spot to look for some tips/advice from the masses.

Comment: ^^ By the way - best of luck! I'm not there yet. Will be ready to launch soon though...

Comment: Was hoping to get a little more feedback on this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not my own experience, but this was an interesting read recently: [BlackBerry App Store, $200 do not pass go, do not upload application.](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/04/01/blackberry-app-store-200-do-not-pass-go-do-not-upload-application.aspx)

It talks a bit about the cost involved in getting an app into the store.

Comment: Although correct at the time, RIM has long since waived the $200 fee.

Answer (score 2):

After submitted blackberry mobile application it take more then 3 weeks to approve also submitted blackberry playbook app it take only one day  to approve. I think right now it more concentrate on playbook application.

Answer (score 1):

We submitted our app about 2 week ago and it's still pending review.